# How I redirect python stdout to C stdin using pipelines in linux

Tags: redirect, stdout, stdin

I have a python script and I want to use the output of it to be the input of other C program. I want to use pipelines, sintax would be:

python_script.py | C_program

but I don't know how to redirect the pythons stdout to C stdin

Answer (score 1):

Redirection is done by the shell. As long as python script writes to stdout and C_program reads from stdin it should work ok.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you doing all right.

For example, if I need to redirect scripts output to program input, I used such construction:

```
$ my_script.py | progr
```

with case if *progr* accepts arguments in you code.

Answer (score 0):

If its not working, maybe your python is writing to standard error and not standard output. If this is the case you need to:

```
( python_script.py 2>&1 ) | C_program
```